# Resume (or start) itertools.permutations from a specific location?

Tags: python

Lets say I run the following script

```
try:
    while 1:
        # Iteration processess of possibel keys
        for length in range(7,8): # only do length of 7
            for attempt in itertools.permutations(chars, length):
                print(''.join(attempt))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keybord interrupt, exiting gracefully anyway."
    sys.exit()
```

It will start printing

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFH
ABCDEFI
ABCDEFJ
etc..
```

But lets say that I exit/close the script and the  iteration stops at `ABCDEFJ`.

Is it possible to start from that location (`ABCDEFJ`), so that I don't have to iterate over the ones that was previously iterated (`ABCDEFG, ABCDEFH, ABCDEFI`)

## Question:

How do I choose start point for `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: I don't know when it was introduced, but in Python 3.4 some iterators can be pickled, including itertools product, permutations, etc. So, I think it is possible to code something to do this.

Comment: Why not just count the iterations and save this to a file and continue by reading the position from the file? next(itertools.islice(itertools.permutations("abcdefg", 3), _pos, None)

Answer (score 1):

Karoly Horvath's answer should work fine if you open the file as "wb" instead of "w".

You can use pickle to store the permutation generator in a file before you stop the script.
When you resume the script read the permutation generator from the file as "rb".

```
from itertools import permutations
import pickle

string = "abcdefg"
to_file = permutations(string, 3)
next(to_file)
next(to_file)

with open('pickle.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(to_file, file)

with open("pickle.pickle", 'rb') as file:
    from_file = pickle.load(file)
    if next(from_file) == next(to_file):
        print("working!")
```

Output:

```
working!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't exit the script, you could simply keep the iterator around and continue consuming it at a later point. Since you start over, the iterator will be created in a state where it starts from the beginning. `itertools.permutations` doesn't have special API for starting in the middle and generators in general don't have this feature since they have internal state that evolves while iterating. So the only way to start in the middle of a fresh generator is to consume a given number of elements and throw them away.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. There's no API to support it, and you cannot serialize these objects:

```
i=itertools.permutations('ABC', 2)
next(i) # ('A', 'B')
next(i) # ('A', 'C')

import pickle
with open('mypickle', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(i, f)

  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle permutations objects
```

You have two choices:

- Skip the permutations you've already seen (as you suggested) or
- Write your own function which accepts a starting point.